# Android com Swipe em uma GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Bom dia a todos preciso de ajuda para fazer com que  uma gridview aceite o evento onFling(deslizar de forma horizontal esquerda direita) sem precisar usar uma pageView ou seja ele seja feito como um "botão" pois vi que o evento não funciona em cima de uma gridView apenas nos locais onde gridview não está. Por favor se não for abusar da boa vontade de quem está ajudando poderia me passar um exemplo pois pesquisei muito e não achei nenhum.
Desde já agradeço muito .

Comment: Rabelos, porque não cria um `GridView` e faz um tratamento customizado do `onTouchEvent` e `onInterceptTouchEvent` para tratar esses casos? Existe também o `SimpleGestureDetector`, que detecta Fling. De uma olhada em http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098198/adding-fling-gesture-to-an-image-view-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

A implementação padrão desse tipo de recurso geralmente acontecesse verticalmente, como podemos verificar no [artigo do Androidtuts4u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling).

Ao mesmo passo, uma implementação usando esse recurso de scroll horizontalmente teria de fazer uso da extensão à classe [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html), tal como demonstrado neste post do stackoverflow: [Android - HorizontalScrollView within ScrollView Touch Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling).

Comment: seria bom incluir um trecho de código, respostas que contenham apenas links não são boas, pois os mesmos podem deixar de ser válidos, invalidando o conteúdo da resposta.